# AngularJS : js-factory service's flow between the calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-factory

I am new to angularjs and so i was going through the basic examples i found online initially just to understand the working and concepts used. When i encountered the concept of "factory service creation" (which is a way to expose data from server to views in and angularjs), i found it difficult to understand the flow between the service's function arguments and the calls made to it .

```
`<html ng-app="countryApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular.js Example</title>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.10/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var countryApp = angular.module('countryApp', ['ngRoute']);

      countryApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
          when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'country-list.html',
            controller: 'CountryListCtrl'
          }).
          when('/:countryName', {
            templateUrl: 'country-detail.html',
            controller: 'CountryDetailCtrl'
          }).
          otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
          });
      });

      countryApp.factory('countries', function($http){
        return {
          list: function(callback){
            $http.get('countries.json').success(callback);
          },
          find: function(name, callback){
            $http.get('countries.json').success(function(data) {
              var country = data.filter(function(entry){
                return entry.name === name;
              })[0];
              callback(country);
            });
          }
        };
      });

      countryApp.controller('CountryListCtrl', function ($scope, countries){
        countries.list(function(countries) {
          $scope.countries = countries;
        });
      });

      countryApp.controller('CountryDetailCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, countries){
        countries.find($routeParams.countryName, function(country) {
          $scope.country = country;
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </body>
</html>`
```

so in the code i ve posted, can anyone let me know or explain the flow between the "factory's list and find methods( keeping the callback argument  particularly in mind)?
  i am not able to understand  why the same factory method is called again by itself( callback argument)

please help me out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Regarding the list function**

When the `CountryListCtrl` controller is instantiated, the `countries` service (which is an object) is being passed as an argument.
Then the `countries.list` function (defined within `countries` service obviously) is being called and passed a callback function.
The `countries.list` function makes a GET request, and if successful (i.e. the $http promise is resolved with success), the anonymous callback function, that was passed in when the function was called in the `CountryListController` controller is called and the $http service passes the returned data as an argument - Which the anonymous function then assigns to the `$scope.countries` property.

The `countries.find` function is the same basic pattern, with the difference that `$routeParams` is picking up the  `/:countryName` from the route, and passing it into the `countries.find` function as an argument for the purpose (it seems) of picking out a specific country from the response data returned by the server and then assigning it to the `$scope.country` property.

Answer (score 0):

the portion of code i am commenting on is

```
countryApp.factory('countries', function($http){

    return {
      list: function(callback){
        $http.get('countries.json').success(callback);
      },
      find: function(name, callback){
        $http.get('countries.json').success(function(data) {
          var country = data.filter(function(entry){
            return entry.name === name;
          })[0];
          callback(country);
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

Here the factory is returning an object with two functions namely list and find.

both the function has a parameter called callback. callback is basically the function that you want to call when the service is executed successfully. As both list and find are going to make Asynchronous calls to server, you would want to be notified when the call is done.

Angular however has a neater way of doing this, called promise. and if we implement promise api the code becomes

```
countryApp.factory('countries', function($http, $q){
        return {
          list: function(){
            var defered = $q.defer();
            $http.get('countries.json').success(function(result){
                 defered.resolve(result);
            })
            .error(function(error){
                 defered.reject(error)
            })
            return defer.promise
          },
          find: function(name){
            var defered = $q.defer();
            $http.get('countries.json').success(function(data) {
              var country = data.filter(function(entry){
                return entry.name === name;
              })[0];
              defered.resolve(country);
            })

            .error(function(error){
                 defered.reject(error)
            })
            return defer.promise;
          }
        };
      });
```

Angulars promise api is very well documented here

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

in short what it says is promise object is a contract that when an asynchronous work is completed then it would either be resolved() (completed successfully) or rejected (completed unsuccessfully) and promise objects then function would be called.

then(success(), error())

your controller would become.

```
countryApp.controller('CountryListCtrl', function ($scope, countries){
        countries.list().then(function(countries) {
          $scope.countries = countries;
        });
      }, function(error){
          console.log("unable to fetch the list of countries : " + error)
      });

      countryApp.controller('CountryDetailCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, countries){
        countries.find($routeParams.countryName).then(function(country) {
          $scope.country = country;
        }, function(error){
          console.log("unable to find the country: " + error)
      }));
```

Hope it helped you.

Comment: thank you for your concern changings.!! ,, well it definitely helped me,at least 80% though,, .. 
 But my question is that, ru  suggesting me to completely ignore the point of using the method i ve used?  I am definitely still getting confused in the  concept of the callback functions used in my method.,

Answer (score 0):

first of all we are defining modules for any application in angularJS.
then we are defining configuration for the module where inside [] we are keeping all required dependency.we can define our own angular directive which will connect java controller to get value in respective format like json etc.Then while defining angular controller we can invoke our defined directive in our angular controller to make availability for data, and from angular controller we can get value to angular view which will display in html or any view page.